# How to end Tkinter propbably if not using the Quit button

Tags: python, tkinter, terminate

I tried to find out a solution for my problem, but I couldn't find one.
I am using Python27 on Windows 7.

I have an easy Tkinter GUI with a button:

```
import Tkinter
import sys

def close_window():
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()


root = Tkinter.Tk()

#exit button
draw_button = Tkinter.Button(root, text="Quit", command = close_window)
draw_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Now if I use the Quit button the program closes and there is not task left of the program. The problem is if someone uses the X-Button to close the Windows or for examples uses Alt+F4, the task is still running. 
For later use I freeze the script to make an executable and if someone uses some method to close the program except the Quit button the task is still running. And if the task is still running he or she can't open the program again, because it is still running in the background and Windows raise an error that the program is still running.

I tried to add some commands after the mainloop but they are all ignored. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks for your help! Max

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about using `WM_DELETE_WINDOW`. For example:

```
import tkinter
import sys

def close_window():
    root.destroy()
    sys.exit()

def win_deleted():
    print("closed");
    close_window();

root = tkinter.Tk()

#exit button
draw_button = tkinter.Button(root, text="Quit", command = close_window)
draw_button.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", win_deleted)

root.mainloop()
```

This will close app with ctr+F4.